# Change the element in a list of lists differently alternating every nth time

Tags: python

I have a list of lists containing information about days in a month.

e.g.

```
[[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]
[Day, Date, id, note]]
```

I would like to iterate through the list of lists setting the element 'id' to "A" for the first five then "B" for the second five and continuing that alternation for as long as the list of lists might be.

I am struggling to get the syntax right using a `for` loop.

Comment: try using a `for i in range` loop and check `i` in the loop

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with helper function. That function will take your list of list, first element you want to change, last one and character you want write into *`id`* field

```
def helper(list_of_list, start, end, char):
    for l in list_of_list[start:end]:
        l[2] = char
```

`list[first:last]` is a slicing syntax, it takes sublist `[list[first], list[first+1] ... list[last-1]]`
Now let's think how we want to call it? The calls should be:

```
helper(ll, 0, 5, "A")
helper(ll, 5, 10, "B")
helper(ll, 10, 15, "C")
...
```

So we can find how to write proper loop

```
c = "A"
for i in range(0, len(ll), 5):
    helper(ll, i, i+5, c)
    c = chr(ord(c) + 1)
```

The last parameter of range is a [*`step`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), it will go through values 0, 5, 10, ...
Last thing is how to increase the letter? We can convert it to ASCII code with `ord()`, add one and change it back to letter with `chr()`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly understood, but from this and your other question that was closed, I suppose you mean that you want something like this:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

# planner = [
#   [Day, Date, id, note], 
#   [Day, Date, id, note],
#   [Day, Date, id, note]
#]

letters = ['A','B']
chunk_size = 5

# we fill the list of letters until we meet the number of chunks
num_chunks = round(len(planner)/chunk_size)
letters_list = list(islice(cycle(letters), num_chunks))

# this let us split the list in groups of x size
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

# we just traverse each group assigning the alternating letters defined above
for group in zip(letters_list, chunker(planner, chunk_size)):
    letter = group[0]
    for day in group[1]:
        day[2] = letter
```

If what you meant is to use a different letter for each chunk instead of only A and B then you can define letters as

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_uppercase
```

The `zip` function returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

The `cycle` function from itertools like the word says, makes an iterator that let you travere the list like a circular linked list, the last element points again to the first element.

The `islice` function from itertools makes an iterator that traverses the iterable defining the start, stop, step values like range.

So mixing `cycle` and `islice` we can traverse the circular list until we meet our maximum which here is the number of chunks to pair letters with chunks.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. I was a bit down when the other question got closed as I'm only starting out with this really. But this answer has done the job, thanks again Kronen.